# Domain registrar who doesn't require signing an agreement as long as a book

Tags: registrar

Most domain name registrars require you to read and sign an agreement which is many tens of thousands of words and further incorporates other documents by reference.  Does anyone know of a registrar that has a short agreement or no agreement?

Comment: Do you not want to read these agreements, or do you want to do things that conflict with them?

Comment: I want to not have to read them and also to not have to say that I read them when I did not read them.  I'm not doing anything that would conflict with what a normal person would consider to be normal use of a domain name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming related question.

Answer (score -2):

Use a local Internet Service Provider or cable company if you have one. This will likely be your path to minimalist catch-22s.

Answer (score -2):

I've used many domain registrars over the years. The TOS is generally complicated (for those of us who read them... er, skim them... sometimes). I currently think Namecheap is the most straightforward and fair. I've never liked their name, but they seem to maintain a degree of community trust and reduce unnecessary burdens.

In the past, I liked Moniker because they kept it professional; however, my opinion has changed. They've been getting more complicated and their agreement seems to give them all protection and me little- if any. Example: This is now at the top of the agreement on how they can use your personal data (caps theirs):

["PLEASE NOTE THAT WE MAY USE INDIVIDUAL INFORMATION FOR ANY LEGALLY PERMISSIBLE PURPOSE IN OUR SOLE DISCRETION."](https://www.moniker.com/legal/privacy-policy)

Nice, huh? That is so brazen that I've been moving my domains from them. Also, Network Solutions is appears to be similarly bad but harder to tell due to length and jargon of the agreement.